# Window AC in a Dormer

Tags: hvac

I just finished our attic, and while central AC is part of the long-term plan, I need a temporary solution for this summer. The only window in the main room is in a dormer in the middle of room, which basically means it’s at the end of a short hallway (maybe about six feet long).

[image: dormer]

My understanding is that a window AC is vastly more effective, but I’m worried that setting it back like that will harm the effectiveness of the unit. Should I consider a free-standing unit instead? Or perhaps upgrade to a higher BTU rating? Or am I just overthinking it? Part of my concern is that if I buy something now, I won’t realize there’s a problem until summer really gets into gear and it’s too late to return things.

Any advice appreciated.

EDIT: Window is a standard single hung, so a regular window AC will fit just fine. Room is 330 sq ft (not including the dormer), which requires an 8K BTU AC according to [this Energy Star chart](https://www.energystar.gov/products/heating_cooling/air_conditioning_room?qt-consumers_product_tab=2#qt-consumers_product_tab). Aside from the obvious monetary consequences of getting more AC than I need (both in purchase price and energy usage), I've also been reading that too much AC can actually lead to a less comfortable environment so I'm really unsure which is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If the window is of the type to accept a window unit (single or double hung, up sliding) use a window unit in the window. I think the cold air will spill out into the room just fine, but, if necessary, you could get an inexpensive pedestal fan or floor box fan to increase circulation.

As far as the BTU rating, how large is the room?

Comment: Just an FYI... casement window air conditioners do exist.  Google it, there are actually a fair number of choices. (I learned that from a different question on this site)

Comment: I do have to say that the chair in that position would impede the flow of air from a window a/c unit, especially if the bottom of the window is low.

Comment: @JimStewart Yep, we have a new home for the chair already picked out. BTU info added to question, good call.

Comment: So do you have a casement window which swings out? If so and you plan for this to be for only for one season, perhaps you should do without. Or consider a minisplit for the attic room as a permanent solution. This would be very efficient and not require ductwork. This can be installed with only a 3" diameter hole through a wall. Is there a gable end on a wall perpendicular to the dormer wall.

Comment: @JimStewart I left out some details to simplify the question, but suffice to say that a minisplit is 1.) very likely what we'll end up with next year and 2.) beyond the scope what I can afford right now having just spent this year's home improvement budget on getting the attic where it is now.

Comment: @Tyson So I deleted my original reply to you because I totally misinterpreted what you were talking about (entirely my fault, let me assure you) and my reply therefore made no sense whatsoever. I don't have casement windows, just standard single-hung.